# how to decode color in xml? Not hex and rgb color

Tags: java, xml, decode

I dont know how decode this color in `XML` file, pleas help me! This color is not in hexadecimal format and not in `RGB` format! And in this code the colors are `XML`, not 6 characters, but 8!

This is xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="0">
    <solid android:color="@0106000B" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Hi @FEIHN "0106000B"  isn't value. I think is referance. But dysfunctional reference. Try to give a color reference with @.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color
You will see, that an ``@`` indicates a resource, for a color it starts with a ``#``. Therefore you can't "decode" but have to search for the reference.